# How do I change the location of Gnome Shell notifications?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

The GNOME Shell has the notifications at the bottom by default. Unfortunately, I like to use the dash to dock and stick it at the bottom. Meaning I can't see the notifications anymore. Any way to change the locations of notifications to elsewhere on the screen?

Answer (score 18):

Installing the extension *[Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/)*. Open the [URL](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/) in Firefox and enable the extension.

[image]

Open the <kbd>Tweak Tool</kbd>

[image]

and configure your settings

[image]

---

After removing the extension, you have to restart your GNOME Shell via

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: nice explanation ,sorry I can't give more than +1;)

Comment: @Ravan Than give me at least one... :P

Comment: I gave sorry network problem it seems!!

Comment: It works in chrome now.

Answer (score 2):

In Gnome shell 3.16, location of notification has been moved to the top. By default it is not possible to change the location of notifications in the Gnome shell, and best to my knowledge there is no extension to accomplish this task, but i could be wrong about that.

Comment: Yes, you're wrong =)

Comment: `.notification,
.notification-banner {
   margin-left: 1200px !important; }
`

Comment: @nodws Awesome, where can i find the relevant CSS file? Rather do that than install something for a single purpose..